# Cross product of columns

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, plsql

How can we do cross product of columns of a table.

Suppose I have table with this data.

```
Name                 Age                  spend                Gender

De                  26                    10                    M
Fu                  27                    29                    F
```

I want output should be

```
De 26 10 M
Fu 26 10 M
De 26 29 M
Fu 26 29 M
De 27 10 M
Fu 27 10 M 
De 27 29 M
Fu 27 29 M

....
```

I am doing the same by putting all the columns in different-different table in a procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this?:

### updated

you can test here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9264d7/2/0

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM test
) x CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT age
    FROM test
) y CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT spent
    FROM test
) z CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT gender
    FROM test
) a;
```

Comment: No, it is not working.

Comment: @Java_Alert updated. I have tested. seems to work well.

Comment: @Java_Alert `DISTINCT` is not required if there is unique value.